# Change text color based on which segue/VC was the source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I did a little research but most examples are still going one `ViewController` to one `ViewController`: I have 4 `TableViewControllers` going to one `TableViewController`.

I have a simple array on `detailsTableViewController`. For one item in my array (which is displaying on a table), I want it to be a different color based on which `TableViewController` this page was called from. I have four different `TableViewControllers` which have a button with segue to `detailsTableViewController`, so I want to know which of these I came from.

Then I want to do this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 1)
    { cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor someColor];}
```

So the logic of what I need is:

```
if (calledSegue="fromRed")
    {if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];}}
else if (calledSegue="fromYellow")
    {if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];}}
else if (calledSegue="fromGreen")
    {if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];}}
else if (calledSegue="fromBlack")
    {if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];}}
```

Can someone help me figure out what I need to do to make this work?
Again, I need to figure out which `TableViewController` was the segue's source and then change the text color for `indexPath == 1` based on that information.

Each segue has a separate identifier as you see in my sample code idea.

Thanks

Comment: Four different source view controllers is no different at all than a single source controller.  Just replicate the code across the other view controllers and change the necessary bits to match what's appropriate for those view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the method `prepareForSegue:sender:` for this kind of job.

First of all, add a property `firstRowColor` to your detail controller, so you can use it on your `tableView` delegate.

Then in each one of your sources view controller, override the method `prepareForSegue:sender:`. This method gets called when a segue is about to be performed, in order to pass data along view controllers. Try something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   // Check if the segue is the right one
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kDetailSegueIdentifier]) {
       // Specify the right color for this source view controller
       [(DetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController setFirstRowColor:[UIColor redColor]];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Where in the detailViewController should I call the firstRowColor? Something like in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @Deannakov yep, you can add it there